# SQL: How to get min date associated with patient value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

Trying to get earliest date associated with each PatientID for this period of time.

Current SQL returns multiple visits/documents within the time period for a patient I need to show only earliest date for patient tied to particular provider in date range.

Multiple Dates for PatientID

[image]

```
    USE EHR 
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    DECLARE @PROV NVARCHAR (255) ='KCOOPER0'
    DECLARE @START_DATE DATETIME = '2017-09-18 00:00:00.000'    
    DECLARE @END_DATE DATETIME = '2017-12-17 23:59:59.999'    
    --DECLARE @START_DATE DATETIME = '2017-10-02 00:00:00.000'    
    --DECLARE @END_DATE DATETIME = '2017-12-31 23:59:59.999'    

    SELECT DISTINCT 
                PS.ID AS AppointmentID
                , CL.Code AS PatientID
--              , SU.NameFirst AS PROVFNAME
--              , SU.NameLast AS PROVLNAME
--              , SU.NameSuffix AS PROVSUFFIX
                , PS.ProviderId
                , PS.ScheduledDateTime AS AppointmentDT
                , PS.Duration
                , PS.[TYPE] AS TypeDescription
                , PS.IsActive as [Status]
                , PS.ExternalId  AS VisitID
  --            , REPLACE(REPLACE(LOC.[Description],'[',''),']','') AS LOCATIONPLACE
              , CDA.CreatedOn AS CDA
               FROM PatientSchedule PS
    INNER JOIN ContactsList CL WITH(NOLOCK) ON PS.PatientID=CL.ReferenceID
    AND CL.Relation = 0
       AND PS.ScheduledDateTime BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE
    INNER JOIN SystemUsers SU WITH(NOLOCK) ON PS.InterfaceCode=SU.InterfaceCode AND SU.Status='1' 
       INNER JOIN EMRDocuments ED ON PS.ID=ED.PatientScheduleId
       AND ED.IsActive=1
       LEFT JOIN 
              (SELECT DISTINCT ED.ID
              ,SU.NPI
              ,ED.PATIENTSCHEDULEID
              ,EDE.CreatedOn
              FROM
              EMRDOCUMENTS ED
              INNER JOIN SystemUsers SU ON ED.ModifiedByID=SU.ID
              AND ED.IsActive = 1
              AND ED.IsSignedOff ='TRUE'
              INNER JOIN EMRDocumentExport EDE ON ED.ID=EDE.DocumentId
              AND EDE.LabCompanyName = 'FollowMyHealth_CCDA'
              ) CDA ON PS.ID=CDA.PatientScheduleId
    WHERE --CL.Code = @PatientID
              su.RegisteredProvider =1
              AND SU.UserID =@PROV 
       ORDER BY CL.Code, CDA.CreatedOn
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the general idea.  You can fill in the details.

```
select your fields
from your tables

join (select patientId, min(the date field you want) minDate
from your tables
where whatever
group by patientId) minDates 

on minDates.patientId = sometable.patientId
and the date field you want = minDate

etc
```

Answer (score 0):

A join-less alternative, using window function and either a Common Table Expression or sticking with a subselect.

using CTE:

```
with mindates as (
    select field1, field2, ..., 
        AppointmentDT,
        min(AppointmentDT) OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID) minptAppointmentDT
    from table
)

select field1, field2, ... , AppointmentDT from mindate_table
where AppointmentDT = minptAppointmentDT
```

using subselect:

```
select field1, field2, ... , AppointmentDT from 
    (select field1, field2, ..., 
    AppointmentDT, 
    min(AppointmentDT) OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID) minptAppointmentDT
    from table) mindates
where AppointmentDT = minptAppointmentDT
```